# Finding the Weierstrass normal form of an elliptic curve.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elliptic-curves

I am given an elliptic curve with homogeneous equation $X^3+Y^3+Z^3=0$ over a field K and I am asked to find the Weierstrass normal form.

I started by noticing that the point $(1,-1,0)$ is in the curve. Then, I find the tangent line at the point:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(X-1)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(Y+1)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(Z-0) = 0$$
to get
$$Y=-X$$ 
But when I plug this in the initial equation I get $$Z^3 = 0$$ and here I stopped the process because these seem strange.

Answer (score 1):

It is just $(1,-1,0)$ is an inflection point.
So I believe the algorithm you were using initially does not work in this case.

The algorithm when your point is an inflection point is as follows:

1) Take tangent at point to be $z=0$

2)choose any line through point, call it $x=0$

3) choose line not through point, call it $y=0$

In step 1) use $z=X+Y$,

2) $Z=0$ passes through your point, so you may set $x=Z$

3) $X=0$ does not, so you may set $y=X$

If you do it correctly, one possible solution is $y^2=x^3-432$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Make a change of variables and use the identity
$$X^3+Y^3=(X+Y)^3-3Y(X+Y)^2+3Y^2(X+Y)$$